# Instrucción switch con múltiples condiciones

Tags: c++

Les dejo mi codigo, esta incompleto, pero quiero saber por que no me deja, el error que me tira es:

> 'X' cannot appear in a constant-expression

Me gustaria que me digan como podria arreglarlo, para que funcione el switch evaluando una variable.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
int X, Y, Casos= 0;
cout << "Ingrese El Valor De X: " << endl;
cin >> X;
cout << "Ingrese El Valor De Y: " << endl;
cin >> Y;
switch (X and Y)
{
    case (X >= 0 and Y >= 0):
        cout << "El Punto De Coordenadas Esta En El Cuadrante 1" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "adsasd";
        break;
}

system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 10):

#### Problema.

> Me gustaria que me digan como podria arreglarlo, para que funcione el switch evaluando una variable.

No se puede.

#### No entiendes cómo funciona la instrucción `switch`.

Las etiquetas de una instrucción `switch` deben ser valores conocidos en [tiempo de compilación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_de_compilaci%C3%B3n), tú estás usando las variables `X` e `Y` cuyo valor sólo es conocido en [tiempo de ejecución](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_de_ejecuci%C3%B3n).

Además, la instrucción `switch` de C++ no permite condiciones múltiples.

#### Solución.

Lo más parecido a lo que necesitas sería lo siguiente:

```
switch ((X >= 0 ? 1 : 0) + (Y >= 0 ? 2 : 0))
{
    case 0:
        std::cout << "X e Y son menores que 0\n";
        break;
    case 1:
        std::cout << "X es mayor que 0, Y es menor que 0\n";
        break;
    case 2:
        std::cout << "X es menor que 0, Y es mayor que 0\n";
        break;
    case 3:
        std::cout << "X e Y son mayores que 0\n";
        break;
}
```

#### ¿Cómo funciona?

La instrucción `switch` evalúa un sólo valor, así que para que compruebe dos variables hacemos un truco, usamos el [operador ternario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario) sobre la variable `X` para crear una expresión que valga `1` cuando ésta variable sea mayor o igual a `0` o `0` en caso contrario.

```
(X >= 0 ? 1 : 0)
```

Para la variable `Y` hacemos lo mismo, pero ésta valdrá `2` si su valor es mayor o igual a `0`:

```
(Y >= 0 ? 2 : 0)
```

Entonces, al sumar los valores de ambas expresiones, tenemos resultados entre `0` y `3` (`0 + 0`, `1 + 0`, `0 + 2`, `1 + 2`) que es lo que usaremos en la instrucción `switch`.

[image]

#### Consejo.

Lee más sobre C++, te fallan varios conceptos básicos.

Answer (score 3):

La sentencia `switch`, traducido "según" entrara en un caso u otro según el valor que tome la variable de la sentencia switch . por ejemplo:

```
int a=0;
switch (a){
case 1: //esto significa que cuando a valga '1' entrara en este caso
//instrucciones
break;
case 2: // cuando a valga 2 , podria ser otro valor cualquiera case 15 o case 'A' ya que los enteros tienen el mismo tamaño que los char
break;
case default: // aqui se entrara en caso de q a no tomase el valor de algun caso anterior como seria en este caso q a vale '0'
}
```

Tú estas introduciendo en los parámetros de la sentencia `switch` una operación lógica la cual dará como resultado true o false, así que no has entendido bien como funciona. en el caso de tu código para que fuese correcto sería:

```
switch (X && Y){
case 0(false):
//instrucciones
break;
case 1(true):
//instrucciones
break;
}
```

Y quedaría así ya que una operación lógica solo puede tomar dos valores.

Comment: Entendí, pero el error que me sale es en la parte del case, yo puse esto : "case (X >= 0 and Y >= 0):" y el error que me sale es este: "[Error] 'X' cannot appear in a constant-expression", tanto para X, como para Y, pero si en cambio, los reemplazo por dos numeros, me compila sin errores.

Comment: tambien probe con "case (X >= 0 && Y >= 0):" , pero me da el mismo error

Comment: Te dice que la X y la Y que son variables enteras, no pueden aparecer en expresiones constantes. Quiere decir como te explique el funcionamiento de switch se hace un case para cada valor con el que quieras actuar, X e Y son variables , cuando las escribes el compilador no sabe que valores tienen , debes poner una expresion constante por ejemplo el valor 1 , el valor de la expresion (X>=0 && Y>=0) puede tomar diferentes valores segun lo que valga X y lo que valga Y. por lo tanto no puede ir ahi, como te dije debes mirar el funcionamiento de la sentencia switch

Comment: por ejemplo se usa mucho en menus , te pongo un pseudocodigo:   segun(opcion){   caso opcion valga 1: se ejecuta la opcion 1 del menu en caso que valga 2 : se ejecuta la opcion 2}

Comment: el valor que tome la variable opcion nos da igual , pero los valores que nosotros queremos evaluar deben ser constante , por ejemplo siempre que opcion valga 1 quiero que se ejecute el metodo metodo1() y cuando valga 2 que se ejecute el metodo metodo2(), si opcion toma cualquier otro valor nos da igual nosotros queremos evaluarlo cuando valga 1 y cuando valga 2

Comment: ah, esta bien, pense que se podia poner una variable en los case

Comment: la solucion al problema que planteas es mejor y mas sencilla con una estructura de if-else anidados

Comment: La hice con un while, pero queria hacerla con un switch :'(

Comment: no todas las estructuras de control de flujo funcionan para lo mismo o de la misma forma no tiene todas las mismas reglas de uso, si no ,con una sola sentencia tendriamos de sobra. Cada estructura de control de flujo tiene su uso , algunas si que es cierto que comparten similitudes y pueden ser usadas indistintamente. Pero por lo general cada estructuras tienen su uso para el cual fueron diseñadas

Answer (score 3):

Como dice @Alexmaister, no parece que hayas entendido aun el funcionamiento de SWITCH. La evaluacion debe ser constante, "x > 0" no es constante.

Puedes modificar tu codigo de la siguiente manera (a ver si así nos entendemos mejor):

```
#include <iostream>;

using namespace std;

int main (){
    int X, Y, Casos= 0;
    cout << "Ingrese El Valor De X: " << endl;
    cin >> X;
    cout << "Ingrese El Valor De Y: " << endl;
    cin >> Y;

    int xPositivo = (X>=0)?1:0;
    int yPositivo = (Y>=0)?1:0;

    switch ( xPositivo )
    {
        case 1:
            switch( yPositivo )
            {
                case 1: // ( +, + )
                    cout << "El Punto De Coordenadas Esta En El Cuadrante 1" << endl;
                    break;
                case 0: // ( +, - ) 
                    cout << "El Punto De Coordenadas Esta En El Cuadrante 4" << endl;
                    break;
            }
            break; // Termina X positivo
        case 0:
            switch( yPositivo )
            {
                case 1: // ( -, + )
                    cout << "El Punto De Coordenadas Esta En El Cuadrante 2" << endl;
                    break;
                case 0: // ( -, - ) 
                    cout << "El Punto De Coordenadas Esta En El Cuadrante 3" << endl;
                    break;
            }
            break; // Termina X negativo
        default:
            cout << "adsasd";
            break;
    }

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Que en realidad, sería más fácil y legible, usando IFs:

```
#include <iostream>;

using namespace std;

int main (){
    int X, Y, Casos= 0;
    cout << "Ingrese El Valor De X: " << endl;
    cin >> X;
    cout << "Ingrese El Valor De Y: " << endl;
    cin >> Y;

    int xPositivo = (X>=0)?1:0;
    int yPositivo = (Y>=0)?1:0;

    if( xPositivo && yPositivo ) // + +
        cout << "El Punto De Coordenadas Esta En El Cuadrante 1" << endl;
    else if ( xPositivo && !yPositivo ) // + -
        cout << "El Punto De Coordenadas Esta En El Cuadrante 4" << endl;
    else if ( !xPositivo && yPositivo ) // - +
        cout << "El Punto De Coordenadas Esta En El Cuadrante 3" << endl;
    else if ( !xPositivo && !yPositivo ) // - -
        cout << "El Punto De Coordenadas Esta En El Cuadrante 4" << endl;
    else cout << "adsasd" << endl;

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: En el primer ejemplo, tienes dos `switch( yPositivo )` ¿Es intencionado?