# ¿Cómo optimizo este código?, ¿alguna función o estructura de datos que lo haga?

Tags: javascript, revisión-de-código, google-apps-script

```
/*Modos de Trabajo*/

var prod      = 1;
var debug     = 0;
var dev       = 0;

/*VALIDAR LOS MODOS DE TRABAJO*/

                  if (prod == 1 && dev == 0 && debug == 0)
                  {
                  Logger.log("Seleccionaste el modo Productivo");
                  }

                  else if (prod == 0 && dev == 1 && debug == 0)
                  {       
                  Logger.log("Seleccionaste el modo dev");
                  }

                  else if (prod == 0 && dev == 0 && debug == 1)
                  {       
                  Logger.log("Seleccionaste el modo Debug");
                  }

                  else if (prod == 0 && dev == 0 && debug == 0)
                  {
                  Logger.log("No seleccionaste ningún modo de trabajo"); 
                  }
```

Comment: Usa una lookup table o un switch.

Comment: intenté con un switch pero no se como, me podrías ayudar con el ejemplo por favor?

Comment: puedes agregar el ejemplo de lo que hiciste?

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si dos parámetros son 1?

Comment: solo puede haber 1 activado, por eso buscaba ideas para poder validar ese código, voy a probar las respuestas que me han dado y voto x la que me ayudo más, gracias!

Comment: No sé cómo recoges y envías los valores, pero podrías, al seleccionar, crear un elemento (array por ejemplo), con una clave que sea el modo y el valor y evaluar ese array. Como no se explica el contexto no se puede suponer nada. Algo que te preguntaría es si siempre se envían los tres valores y por qué...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre que puedes usar un `switch`, basado en la pregunta:

- [Instrucción switch con múltiples condiciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103496/instrucci%C3%B3n-switch-con-m%C3%BAltiples-condiciones/103566#103566) .

```
var valor = (prod == 1 ? 1 : 0) +
            (debug == 1 ? 2 : 0) +
            (dev == 1 ? 4 : 0);

switch (valor)
{
    case 0: Logger.log("No seleccionaste ningún modo de trabajo"); break;
    case 1: Logger.log("Seleccionaste el modo Productivo"); break;
    case 2: Logger.log("Seleccionaste el modo Debug"); break;
    case 4: Logger.log("Seleccionaste el modo dev"); break;
    default: Logger.log("Detengan a este loco peligroso"); break;
}
```

Comment: Hola @PaperBirdMaster , probé tu código y me generó este error : Falta ")" en el paréntesis. 
 yo lo veo bien pero me marca error en la declaración de la variable "valor"

Comment: Es un `TypeError`, faltan los signos de interrogación en lugar de `:` dos puntos. `(debug == 1 ? 2 : 0)`

Comment: Exacto!, muchas gracias @JoseHermosillaRodrigo ya corrió

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo gracias por avisar del typo. Pablo, gracias por la correción.

Answer (score 2):

un ejemplo de switch en C seria el siguiente, igual los switch tiene formas similares en muchos lenguajes.

```
void main(){

    int variable = 0;
    // Leo del teclado un numero y lo almaceno en variable
    printf("Ingrese un valor: ");
    scanf("%d",&variable);
    /*
    ** Ejecuto distintas instrucciones de acuerdo al valor de variable
    */
    switch(variable){

       case 0:
           /* Codigo cuando sea 0 */
           break;

       case 1:
           /* codigo cuando sea 1 */
           break;

        default:
           /* codigo cuando la variable no tenga ninguno de los valores
           ** definidos por el desarrollador */
           break

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Rudy, gracias por tu respuesta, es muy similar la sintaxis en GAS y agradezco tu tiempo, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

a diferencia de los otros ejemplos, propongo esta forma, podria obviar el `if` inclusive, pero lo deje para validar y garantizar la entrada de datos, de esta manera es optima y entendible a cualquier usuario (seria el equivalente al funcionamiento de ENUM en MySQL)

```
var modos_trabajo = ["prod" ,"dev", "debug"];
var modoActual = 0;
if (modoActual > (modos_trabajo.length - 1) || modoActual < 0 ){
    Logger.log("No seleccionaste ningún modo de trabajo"); 
}else{
    Logger.log("Seleccionaste el modo " + modos_trabajo[modoActual]);
}
```

como trabajo con un **`Array`** le asigno una posición a cada estado

```
0 : prod
1 : dev
2 : debug
```

de esta forma garantizo que solo sea un solo estado el válido

Comment: Te ha faltado explicar que trabajas con los valores 0,1 y 2

Comment: no entendí la parte de: 0 : prod
1 : dev
2 : debug

Answer (score 1):

Cambiando los parámetros de entrada a uno sólo, ya que todos son mutuamente excluyentes:

```js
//modo puede ser 0,1,2

function seleccionaModo(modo) {
  const modos=['productivo','debug','desarrollo']
  if (modos[modo]) { // cualquier valor distinto de 0,1,2 da undefined (falso)
    console.log('Seleccionaste el modo '+modos[modo]);
  } else {
    console.log('No seleccionaste ningún modo válido');
  }
}

seleccionaModo(0);
seleccionaModo(1);
seleccionaModo(2);
seleccionaModo(3);
```

Comment: Hola pablo, gracias por responder, puedo aplicar esa función en otro caso, ya me diste una idea mas clara, saludos