# evaluar multiples variables en una sentencia if

Tags: c++, variables

he estado desarrollando un programa para encontrar contraseñas en un juego llamado keep talking and nobody explodes, en la que uno de los desafíos es encontrar la contraseña de 5 letras correcta de una lista de contraseñas. Para resolverlo se te dan  6 posibles letras para cada casilla de la palabra (por ejemplo en la primera columna podrían aparecer (aleatoriamente) las letras:
a
o
q
w
e

por lo que las posibles contraseñas son: about, again, which, where y every, pues esas son las contraseñas que empiezan con esas letras, en las siguientes columnas se te dan mas letras hasta que puedes determinar la contraseña correcta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo estoy intentando crear un programa en C++ para encontrar la contraseña de forma automática, pero me encontré con un problema, a la hora de descartar  contraseñas incorrectas termino con un código así:

Aquí por ejemplo en caso de que ninguna de las letras sea una "a" determino como incorrectas todas las contraseñas que tienen la a en esa posición:

```
if(letra1 != a && letra2 != a && letra3 != a && letra4 != a && letra5 != a && letra6 != a){           
again, after, about = 0
}
```

Pero esto me deja un código feo en el que tengo que usar muchas veces la letra que estoy comprobando, intente hacer esto:

```
if(letra1, letra2, letra3, letra4, letra5, letra6 != a){                        
    again, after, about = 0;
}
```

Pero C++ parece no leer eso como yo esperaba.

¿Alguien conoce alguna forma de resolver este problema? ¿O tal vez alguien que pueda dejarme un programa que use listas/arrays? Habría probado a usar una lista de elementos, pero eso es muy avanzado para mi.

Si alguien tiene una sugerencia de una forma mas sencilla de conseguir realizar esto tambien lo agradeceria.   :)

Comment: son sólo letras ascii? a-z no ñ ?

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Tene en cuenta que si lo que haces resuelve el problema, entonces no tenes un problema. lo que estas preguntando parece basado en opiniones. porque ya sabes que hacer y como resolverlo.. cualquier respuesta es valida si tambien resuelve el problema, por lo tanto no hay una respuesta correcta.

Comment: si, solo letras del alfabeto ingles

Comment: Relacionado: [`switch` con múltiples condiciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/103496/2742).

Comment: Si usaras un array para guardar cada letra, tranquilamente podrías hacer un ciclo `for` y preguntar una sola vez por cada letra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pero esto me deja un código feo en el que tengo que usar muchas veces la letra que estoy comprobando, intente hacer esto:
>
> ```
> if(letra1, letra2, letra3, letra4, letra5, letra6 != a){                        
>     again, after, about = 0;
> }
> ```
>
> Pero C++ parece no leer eso como yo esperaba.

La manera en que se interpreta esa instrucción en C++ es la siguiente: se evalúa cada una de las expresiones separadas por coma y se descartan todas excepto la última. Es decir, evalúa `letra1` y la descarta, `letra2` y la descarta, hasta llegar a `letra6 != a` y la usa como resultado de la expresión completa.

Este es el comportamiento del [operador coma `,`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator).

---

Lo que pretendes hacer no es posible en C++, es decir: no existe manera de simplificar ese tipo de comparación<sup>1</sup>. Lo que sí puedes hacer es comparar de otra manera, por ejemplo guardando las letras que quieres comparar en una formación<sup>2</sup> y operando sobre ella:

```
char letras[] {letra1, letra2, letra3, letra4, letra5, letra6};

if (std::count(std::begin(letras), std::end(letras), 'a') == 0) {
    // Ninguna letra es 'a'
}
```

---

1. Y hasta donde yo se, no hay ningún lenguaje que lo permita de la manera que indicas.
2. También conocida como arreglo o en Inglés: array.

Comment: _"Hasta donde yo sé no hay ningún lenguaje que lo permita en la manera que indicas"_. Python se puede acercar ligeramente: `if 'a' not in (letra1,letra2,letra3,letra4,letra5,letra6)`

Comment: **Hasta donde yo se**. Entre lo que no se pueden haber miles de cosas, entre ellas, sin duda, Python.

Comment: No era una crítica, era para tu información :-)

Comment: Para mi información y para la información del resto de nuestros lectores ¡manténganse en antena! :*

Answer (score 3):

Se me ocurre que podrías usar un switch case:

```
switch(a){
    case letra1:
    case letra2:
    case letra3:
    case letra4:
    case letra5:
    case letra6:
        break;
    default:
        again, after, about = 0;
        break;
}
```

Comment: C++ me dice que eso no es posible porque las variables de letra tendrian que ser constantes

Comment: Además de que como señala @Mat no se pueden usar variables en las etiquetas del `switch`, ambos estáis fallando en la asignación pues `again, after, about = 0` sólo pone a cero el último elemento.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un método aparte que compruebe la condición y lo llames cada vez que lo necesites:

```
public bool condicion(String letra){
   if(letra1 != letra && letra2 != letra && letra3 != letra && letra4 != letra && letra5 != letra && letra6 != letra){
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Ahora para usarlo en un método:

```
if(condicion("a")){           
   again, after, about = 0
}
```

Y así todo correcto.